# when i listing files in google drive, i got extra file

Tags: python, google-drive-api

In this code i got extra file, which not contain in my google drive. I check this files in another disk and now they showed when i ask file from googleDrive, but i cant find this files in google drive. How get only local files from my google disk.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import httplib2
import io
from apiclient import discovery, errors
from oauth2client import client, tools, file
from apiclient import http

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(parents=[tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

import auth

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'credentials.json'
APPLICATION_NAME = 'Python Task "Cloud"'
authInst = auth.auth(SCOPES, CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, APPLICATION_NAME)
credentials = authInst.getCredentials()

http_for_drive = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
drive_service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http_for_drive)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(http_for_drive))

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    dictItems = {}

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            dictItems[item['name']] = item['id']
            print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't work out what you're asking. What is the name of the extra file? Did you have one of the files open at the time?

Comment: @roganjosh for example i check some file in url, after i listing google drive and this file added in disk

Comment: @roganjosh check google doc*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i make function which output files folder being in your google drive folder

```
def retrieve_all_files(service):
    """ RETURNS a list of files, where each file is a dictionary containing
        keys: [name, id, parents]
    """

    query = "trashed=false"

    page_token = None
    L = []

    while True:
        response = service.files().list(q=query,
                                             spaces='drive',
                                             fields='nextPageToken, files(id, name, parents, size, parents, owners)',
                                             pageToken=page_token).execute()
        for file in response.get('files', []):  # The second argument is the default
            if file.get('owners')[0]['me']:
                L.append({"name": file.get('name'), "id": file.get('id'), "parents": file.get('parents'), "size": file.get('size'),
                    "owners": file.get('owners')})

        page_token = response.get('nextPageToken', None)  # The second argument is the default

        if page_token is None:  # The base My Drive folder has None
            break

    return L
```